# Why SuperClass Constructor is not invoked?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class `Demo` as follows :

```
public class Demo extends Animal{

private int id;

public Demo(){


    System.out.println("ChildClass Constructor Called!!!");
}

public Demo(int id , String name){

    super(name);
    this.id = id;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Demo d = new Demo();

    System.out.println(d.id + " " + d.name);
}
```

and another class `Animal` as follows :

```
public class Animal{

String name;

Animal(){

    System.out.println("SuperClass Constructor Called!!!");
}

Animal(String name){

    this.name = name;
}
```

The Output for this program is :

```
SuperClass Constructor Called!!!
ChildClass Constructor Called!!!
0 null
```

But when i include `this()` in the `Demo` class the output is as follows :

```
ChildClass Constructor Called!!!
0 null
```

Superclass Constructor is not called ? What is the Reason?

In another Example :

```
public class A {

    A() {

        this(0);
        System.out.println("Hi ");

    }

    A(int x) {

        this(0, 0);
        System.out.println("Hello");

    }

    A(int x, int y) {

        System.out.println("How are you");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A ob = new A();

    }
}
```

The Output is :

```
How are you
Hello
Hi
```

Why are the `print` statements not executed after `this()` is executed?

Comment: Your superclass `Animal` has two constructors, one that takes no arguments and another one that takes a `String`. Only the one without args prints a message. In the constructor `Demo(int id, String name)` you call the `Animal(String)` constructor by using `super(name)` so the no-args constructor that prints the message is not called.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your first exaxmple correctly. But in the second example with `Class A`, in your main() method you're creating an object of class A using the default constructor. There you are calling another constructor `A(int x)` and from there another constructor `A(int x, int y)`. After this constructor your print statements are executed.

Comment: What is the execution order of print statements?

Comment: @NishanthG the execution order of print statement in this case is, what you are currrently getting as an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when i include this() in the Demo class the output is as follows

If you include `this()` in the following constructor:

```
public Demo() {
    this (0,null);
    System.out.println("ChildClass Constructor Called!!!");
}
```

You are calling the second Demo constructor `Demo(int id , String name)`, which calls a different `Animal` constructor - `Animal(String name)` (since it contains `super(name)` and not `super()`) - that doesn't print anything.

Therefore the only output you get is:

```
ChildClass Constructor Called!!!
0 null
```

> Super class Constructor is not called ? What is the Reason?

A super class constructor is called (some super class constructor must be called), just not the one you expected.

Answer (score 0):

when you use this(), it means you are invoking current(self) class constructor.

```
ChildClass Constructor Called!!!
0 null
```

Your answer predict you have call this(0,null) in Demo class Constructor like.

```
public Demo() {
this (0,null);
System.out.println("ChildClass Constructor Called!!!");
}
```

This code represent you are invoking Demo class Constructor which takes two parameters and it calls

```
public Demo(int id , String name){

super(name);
this.id = id;
}
```

above constructor.now above Constructor having super(name) means invoke super class Constructor which takes one parameter of String type.

```
Animal(String name){
this.name = name;
}
```

so default constructor of Animal class not called.

Always remember, super() call parent class constructor based on parameters and this() call child class constructor based on parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried?

```
  public Demo(){
    super();

    System.out.println("ChildClass Constructor Called!!!");
}
```

This happens because you are defining a default constructor for your Demo class.

Comment: There is never a need to invoke `super()` explicitly. If no superclass constructor is invoked, and a no-args ctor exists, the compiler will insert the `super()` call. So doing this wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for informing, I've just realized after I posted. Had to check twice before posting :)